# iOS equivalent of Android's stepper for multiple steps

Tags: mobile, android, ios, multi-step

In Android there are detailed [guidelines](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/steppers.html) about step by step navigation/input.

For example something like this:

[image]

In iOS there are [guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Controls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH15-SW1) (further down the page) for page controls, which are equivalent to the dots in the screenshot. But they do not seem to be intended to be used as step controls.

**Now I would like to have the same functionality as in the screenshot in iOS, what would be the equivalent to Android there?**

**EDIT:** I need this form of structure in my app because the user is sometimes supposed to enter information step by step.

Comment: A lot of popular iOS applications use the Dots to represent the current position for onboarding the user. Check it out here: https://www.quora.com/What-iOS-apps-have-the-best-onboarding-screen-flow

Also, you can implement a "Next" button without the dots.

Comment: @SwapnilBorkar Thanks for the advice, but in my case it is not an onboarding that I need this design for. At some points in the app the user is supposed to enter input in steps, so I am looking for a way to correctly present that.

Comment: I would only recommend following the onboarding flow if the data needed to be entered in your app isn't sort of a form. The above method serves well for <5 entries. Anything more than that and a form like interface is more suitable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off there are very few areas where I'd recommend the onboarding screen flow suggestion. Not that those don't have beautiful designs, but a lot of research shows that users do not read them and as they become more popular users get used to swiping through so they can explore the app on their own, but I digress.

As far as the step by step navigation, I'd recommend taking a look at the iOS new phone setup or recent OS upgrade process seen partially in the attached image. I don't want to reset my phone to get the whole flow but this would feel familiar to me. As you progress you're given the typical "< back" and "next >" options in the upper left and right corners. As an iOS user, I've been through it in the setup process and in my opinion would be your best bet at mimicking something from the OS.

[image]